# How do you filter out retweets while searching for tweets using using the TwitteR package in R?

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to do some text analytics using the searchTwitter function in the TwitteR package to search for tweets. However I get a lot of tweets which are retweeted and hence are repeated lots of times. Do you know how to filter out these retweets such that I only get the original tweet?

Comment: Are you using `tm` package for text analytics?

Comment: Have you tried the `strip_retweets(tweets)` function from the twitteR package?

Comment: @Gaurav Yes, I am using the tm package for text analytics.

Comment: @Dave, strip_retweets worked perfectly. Thanks :)